# Factorial multithreading in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to calculate a factorial `(n!)` splitting it in multiple parts. That is in `"t"` Threads, each one of them calculating several values.

```
1. t1= 1..n-1/t 
2. t2= n-1/t+1..2*(n-1)/t
3. t3= 2*(n-1)/t+1.. 3*(n-1)/t
```

and so on.

And afterwards, when all threads are finished, the main thread would compute `n! = t1 * t2 * t3`

Does someone know how to write something like this in Python?

Thank you very much!

Comment: No it doesn't, @Carcigenicate. Take 12!, for example. You could compute 1 • 2 • 3 • 4 in one thread, 5 • 6 • 7 • 8 in another, and 9 • 10 • 11 • 12 in a third. Then the main thread would compute the product of those three pieces. It would certainly be convenient if you _already had_ the previous value, though, because 12! = 11! • 12. Perhaps you're thinking of Fibonacci?

Comment: @RobKennedy Oops. You're right.

Comment: Your plan would work, but bear in mind that threads in Python do not provide performance boost, so you will have to use the `multiprocessing` module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). This is going to be a BIG hammer for this problem.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that you want to split the problem into intervals of unequal length. You want to make the lower intervals longer, and the higher shorter. This is because Python uses arbitrary precision integers, and multiplication is an operation that is linear in the size of the integer, not a constant-time operation.